# TextWrangler - replace every second line-break with comma

Tags: text, grep, line-breaks, textwrangler

I have a text file containing only text lines like this:

```
abcdefg
2009
hijklmnop
2012
```

I want to replace every second line-break with a comma. So it should look like this:

```
abcdefg, 2009
hijklmnop, 2012
```

How can I do this in TextWrangler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've no idea what `TextWrangler` is but you haven't had an answer in about a day and you mention `grep` so maybe `awk` is an option to and if so it's trivially:

```
$ awk '{ORS=(NR%2?", ":"\n")}1' file
abcdefg, 2009
hijklmnop, 2012
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That did it. Just to extend it for the rest, add this at the end of the line to save the output in a file: `> outputfile`